# Library like gmail's "Report a bug" functionality

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Does anyone know a .net library for winforms to accomplish the same functionality for my applications as the "Report a bug" link provides in gmail app?

Screenshot with highlight/blackout feature seems very useful.

Comment: "Blackout" doesn't work so well in Windows applications. They're not the same as Web applications, and you're *absolutely* not doing your users any favors in trying to make them work similarly.

Comment: You may want to check out Winqual also

Answer (score 1):

It's not freeware, but redgate has a library called [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/features/#automated-error-reporting), which does support error reporting out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NBug](http://www.nbusy.com/projects/nbug) library though it doesn't feature a 'on-request feedback' just yet (only with >v1.1). Currently it does reports all unhanded exceptions.

There is also [Google Breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/) for handling SEH exceptions, but that is in native code.